# How to keep background image in place and indent all hyperlinks 5 cm to the right of screen?

Tags: html, css

Hi all i got a background image in my page and want to move all my hyperlinks 5 centimeter to the right of the screen so it doesn't cover the background image. could you guys tell me how i can achieve this task?Currently i got only few hyperlinks in my page but later on i want to add more stuff and want to indent all of those things to the right of screen by 5 centimeters.

```
<body id="ct600_bodytag" style="background:url(./images/bg.jpg) no-repeat fixed top center #fff;">
```

Comment: Not sure if I completely understand the question, but if you are going to add hyperlinks into the body can you simply give them a margin left?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it possible to give all html codes in body margin left ? could you show me how ?

Comment: Using the bellow answers you should have no problem, hope all goes well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to give everything in body margin just add it in the tag

```
body{
margin-left:5cm;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gH2eP/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use something like this in your `<head>`-tag?

```
<style>
 body *
 {
   margin-left: 5cm;
 }
</style>
```

or even simpler

```
<style>
  body
  {
    padding-left: 5cm;
  }
</style>
```